# Algolia - Unity/C# | How to use REST API in Unity

Tags: rest, api, unity-game-engine, webrequest, algolia

I'm trying to use the PLACES REST API of Algolia in Unity. https://community.algolia.com/places/api-clients.html#rest-api

The documentation provides examples of how to use it:

```
$ curl -X POST ‘https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query’ 
-H ‘X-Algolia-Application-Id: YourApplicationId’ 
-H ‘X-Algolia-API-Key: YourAPIKey’ 
–data ‘{“query”: “Paris”}’
```

Using UnityWebRequest, the syntax is the following:

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query", form);
www.SetRequestHeader("X-Algolia-Application-Id", "XXXXX");
www.SetRequestHeader("X-Algolia-API-Key", "XXXXXX");
```

Where form has been:

> Unity WWWForm

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("data", "{\"query\": \"Paris\"}");
AND
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("query", "Paris");
```

> string

```
"{\"query\": \"Paris\"}"
```

> string json

```
JsonUtility.ToJson(new AlgoliaQuery { query = "paris" });
```

The connection is successful but I keep receiving errors in return

```
{"message":"lexical error: invalid char in json text. Around '%7b%22quer' near line:1 column:1","status":400}
```

The error varies in the invalid char position depending on the type of attempt.

Please, if you can provide any help would be amazing!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the Unity project can leverage .NET Standard or .NET 4.5 you could directly use the [Algolia .NET API client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-csharp) to embed Algolia search in your project.

Here is a [sample application](https://github.com/algolia/unity-example) I made using both Algolia and Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer! https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-post-url-jsondata-sending-broken-json.414708/

```
var request = new UnityWebRequest("https://places-dsn.algolia.net/1/places/query", "POST");
byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Algolia-Application-Id", "XXXXXX");
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Algolia-API-Key", "XXXXXXX");
yield return request.SendWebRequest();
```

it works now. I hope this will be useful for someone.